# Why do we need to provide the context in MaterialPageRoute when the build method of the widget is also taking the context?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Why do we need to provide the **context** in **MaterialPageRoute** when the *build method of the widget* is also taking the **context**?

```
onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      title: Text("Second Route"),
                    ),
                    body: Center(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Text('Go back!'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              );
            },
```

Comment: *"Why do we need to provide the context in MaterialPageRoute [...]"* - we dont, those are the params that `MaterialPageRoute` accepts: `{@required WidgetBuilder builder,
RouteSettings settings,
bool maintainState: true,
bool fullscreenDialog: false}`

Comment: I didn't get the point.

Comment: i mean that you dont need to provide any context - i posted all the params that can be provided to `MaterialPageRoute` constructor